# ImportError: cannot import name 'resource_loader' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1'

Tags: python, tensorflow, rasa

I am building a chatbot using `rasa`. When I try to run `rasa train`, I get the following error.

```
from tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1 import resource_loader
ImportError: cannot import name 'resource_loader' from partially initialized module 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1'
```

Could someone help me identify what library I could change to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`resource_loader`seems to be missing. Try to upgrade tensorflow `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` or RASA `pip install --upgrade rasa`